# How to convert a MEMORY table into a CACHED one on HsqlDB?

Tags: hsqldb, caching

I have created a HsqlDB database and inserted a lot of data in it already. The tables were create in default mode, i.e.,  the table type is MEMORY.

Not I want to switch those tables to CACHED mode since they are getting larger and larger. The HsqlDB 1.8 guide says the cached tables can be created by using command

```
CREATE CACHED TABEL ...
```

Is there any way to alter the existing tables into CACHED without losing any data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, when your table name is mytable and you want to change it to cached.

With version 2.x there is a command for this:

```
SET TABLE mytable TYPE CACHED
```

With version 1.8.x you need to shutdown the database first. Then edit the .script file and modify the line for the table

`CREATE MEMORY TABLE mytable` to `CREATE CACHED TABLE mytable`

After saving the .script file, open your database as normal.